# ASP.NET identity Multiple Login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am trying to implement a administrator login page (Roles = "Admin"), but it seems like the authentication of ASP.NET Identity has only one authentication Cookies. I really want to implement 2 distinct login pages one for Admin Group and other for User group. Any suggestions or help?

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            CookieName = "_user",

            CookiePath = "/",
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/Logoff"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account. 
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            CookieName = "_admin",
            CookiePath = "/Admin",
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Admin/Home/Login"),
            //LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/Logoff"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account. 
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
```

Login Controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                {
                    var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Identity);

                    if (user.IsInRole("Admin"))
                    {

                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return View("Login");
                    }
                }
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is for ASP.NET **Core** - right??

Comment: *Authentication* means finding out who the user is. You don't need multiple cookies for this. What you ask for is authorization - once you know who the user is, deciding what is allowed and what isn't. You don't need cookies for this at all. You need to use ASP.NET Core Identity's mechanisms to assign a role to that user

Comment: it's ASP.NET MVC :D

Comment: so, multiple logins with ASP.NET identity isn't possible?

Comment: You do not need multiple login pages.... How would the system know to which one to redirect you?

Comment: You can have many login pages... But the user would be responsible to know the url that they should be using.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Jonathan Alfaro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2495728/jonathan-alfaro) said.
You don't need two cookies, you need to protect your admin resources(Action or Controller) using Authorize attribute. For example:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult AdminOnly()
{
    return View();
}
```

This action is available for users who have Admin role.